# How to set something to happen in a certain amount of time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, timer

in this [JSFiddle](http://bit.ly/YGAn2T), as you can see the red square moves from one tile to the next extremely fast, how can I set it so it takes about 0.2 seconds to get from one tile to the next?

Comment: If you need anymore explanation to answer this question ... just ask.

Comment: I do not see the reds, where exactly are they?

Comment: That's way too much code in that jsFiddle, nobody's going to read that. Please construct a simpler code sample.

Comment: @Jarrod how could I animate it between points?

Comment: Searching for "canvas animation" shows a whole bunch of results. Basically you need some sort of timer that will cause a redraw for an intermediate step of the animation, and in that timer you draw the moving box at the appropriate position in between the two points.

Comment: Because you've built your own renderer, you'll also need to handle the animation yourself. Set up a `setInterval` loop to move by a few pixels every 100 milliseconds of the player needs to move (store the current and desired locations separately), or something like that.

Comment: The reason it goes "extremely fast" is because there is no animation between points. It's either at point A OR it's at point B. No in between.

Comment: I don't see *anything* move.  Am I supposed to click something?

Comment: @EychPixels By moving your object (changing the x,y values) after a specified amount of time, closer to it's destination.

Comment: @gilly3 looks like this fiddle dosent work in internet explorer or are you using chrome?

Comment: I tried in several browsers.  I finally realized I need to use the arrow keys on my keyboard.  It works in IE just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the question in your title, the way to execute some JavaScript after a given period of time is with `setTimeout()` (or `setInterval()`).

To animate movement, it's the same on a computer as it was for Walt Disney's hand drawn animation.  Draw a bunch of pictures with a small amount of change in each one and show them one at a time, waiting a small amount of time before displaying each frame.

So, to do that, you need to calculate each frame.  Find the difference between the destination position and the current position and chop those differences up into steps.  Then, draw the image moving the position by one step until the current position matches the destination.

[jsfiddle.net/kmHZt/79](http://jsfiddle.net/kmHZt/79/)

```
var lastPos;
function draw() {
    var endPos = {
        x: (playerX - vX) * 32,
        y: (playerY - vY) * 32
    };
    var pos = $.extend({}, endPos, lastPos);
    var step = {
        x: (endPos.x - pos.x) / 10,
        y: (endPos.y - pos.y) / 10
    };
    drawStep();

    function drawStep() {
        context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        for (y = 0; y <= vHeight; y++) {
            for (x = 0; x <= vWidth; x++) {
                theX = x * 32;
                theY = y * 32;
                context.drawImage(tiles[board[y + vY][x + vX]], theX, theY, 32, 32);
            }
        }
        context.fillStyle = 'red';
        pos.x += step.x;
        pos.y += step.y;
        context.fillRect(pos.x, pos.y, 32, 32);
        if (Math.round(pos.x - endPos.x) + Math.round(pos.y - endPos.y) == 0) {
            lastPos = pos;
            return;
        }
        setTimeout(drawStep, 20);
    }
}
```